# How to replace a string in a URL field when outputting it in a template file

Tags: 7, entities

I created a new field for URL. What would the best way to replace certain strings in the URL when outputting the field into the field--field_url.tpl.php file be?

For example, in http://example.com/master/m/ I need to remove the "http://" part, and replace *master* with *slave*.

It is a single field; there will be no `foreach()` loops.

==== edit after using preprocess ===
i got a undefined index: field_url

with the devel i get this

```
field_url
   und
     0
       value
```

i put in the preprocess

```
$link = $variables['field_url'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

$link = str_replace('http://', "", $link);

$link = str_replace('master', 'slave', $link);

$variables['link'] = $link;
```

is this right?

====== entire hook =======

```
function lessxless_preprocess_field(&$variables)
{ 
    $link = $variables['field_url'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; // grab value

    $link = str_replace('https://', "", $link); // trim http://

    $link = str_replace('master', 'slave', $link);

    $variables['link'] = $link;
}

sites/all/themes/lessxless/template.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a [preprocess function](http://drupal.org/node/223430) in your template.php for this. In your case, hook_preprocess_field() will be easiest to work with - for an example of how this is implemented, check out the API documentation for [template_preprocess_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7).

Remember, $variables is passed into preprocess hooks by reference. From within your hook_preprocess_field(), instead of modifying the field data directly (in case you need it elsewhere), you could do something like this after checking that you're operating on the right field:

```
/* devel's dpr() is handy for seeing where in the $variables array it lives if you 
   don't have a debugger handy. If you see 'und', that's the value for the LANGUAGE_NONE
   constant. It's considered best practice to use the constant instead. */
$slave_link = $variables['field_url'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];  
$slave_link = str_replace("http://", '', $slave_link); // Trim http://
$slave_link = str_replace("master", "slave", $slave_link); // s/master/slave
$variables['slave_link'] = $slave_link;  /* You can now access this variable from your
                                            field--field_url.tpl.php as $slave_link */
```

You may also need to [clear your cache](http://drupal.org/node/42055) after making these changes.

Comment: thanks David, can you give me an example what i should write in $foo that i should be seeing with devel themer info

Comment: You wouldn't find it in Devel Themer to the best of my knowledge. After creating your hook_preprocess_field(), download/enable the <a href="http://drupal.org/project/devel">Devel</a> module, and put "dpr($variables);" in your new hook. It will print the data structure of $variables when the function is called, and you'll reference the value you're looking for by its keys in your function. Note that arrays may be nested, so it may look something like "$slave_link = $variables['foo']['bar']['baz'];" when all is said and done.

Comment: got a undefined index, i edited the question

Comment: Updated my answer (apologies for the poorly formatted link above; didn't notice until it was too late to edit). Would you mind posting your entire hook_preprocess_field() and the path to the file it's in relative to your Drupal root? It may help me help you debug the undefined index issue.

Comment: sure, here it is, in the edits

Comment: the undefined variable is still there, so i did it another way, instead of using the preprocess function, i just get rid of every useless elements in the field--field_url.tpl.php, and did a str_replace in the node.tpl.php with render($content['field']), its not ideal though, since if there is a chance to add more than one url, it won't work.